# How to run one particular function in a shell script to be run on a daily basis

Tags: linux, shell

I am creating a script which has two function (funcA,funcB), funcA one has the entire server login logs and store it in file1  and the other function captures the login logs on daily basis. I would like to call this second funcB on a daily basis so that it append this logs to the first file. So that the incremental value is added to the file1. How can I achieve it.

Comment: Use `cron` to run scheduled jobs.

Comment: ...though the more modern alternative, as opposed to cron, would be a systemd timer periodically invoking a oneshot service.

Answer (score 0):

Use `crontab -e` and add:

```
00 00 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to run just one function, not the entire script. (I do consider the question to be too broad, insofar as they're merging that together with the scheduling-invocation question, which is distinct and prone to a different set of answers; but as it is, this only covers half of what's being asked).